# Android - slow data retrieve

Tags: android, httprequest

I have an issue, cause my app asks many API requests and because that became really slow.
What is better than I have couple objects which everyone I need to fill up with data.
So first I have request to get a list of object and then every object ask for his data individual.

What is better technique ? Keep each request in different async thread or
do them all in one async thread?

Is there is imported the for each request I got different method with their own
HttpClient?

There are some tricks or methods which are should help me increase request speed?

Comment: This is very difficult to discern. Could you please proof read this and try to word it better.

Comment: If you are using a public web service, check that they allow you to use multiple requests at once or have a request per time limit. Multiple threads getting information is usually faster than doing that singlethreaded - unless you are limited by network speed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to ask how to do numerous http request without having a slow app. What I'm doing is using ExecutorService to create a thread pool and then I make a runnable for each request and then starts them with execute.